# Where does instance go when not assigned to variable?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

What happens to the lifetime of the Employee instance in the following snippet?

```
Department dept = new Employee(10).GetDepartment();
```

The Employee class is created and not assigned to any variable.  How long does the Employee instance last in this case?

Are there any negative side effects to doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of it this way:

```
Employee __temp = new Employee(10);
Department dept = __temp.GetDepartment();
```

*This isn't really what's happening but it's useful to help explain what is happening.*

In this case, `__temp` is *elegible* to be cleaned up by the garbage collector as soon as `__temp.GetDepartment()` finishes executing. It won't *actually* be collected until the next garbage collection cycle occurs, which will happen when the runtime determines it's necessary.<sup>1</sup>

Writing code like

```
Department dept = new Employee(10).GetDepartment();
```

simply saves you from having to declare an intermediate variable yourself. There are no negative side effects of writing code like that and it's a very common practice.

*1: There are ways to manually force a collection cycle, but 99.9% of the time you don't need to and shouldn't do it.*

Comment: This is a misleading answer. It makes it sound like the compiler creates a temporary variable which would prevent collection of the `Employee` instance until the temporary variable goes out of scope, instead of it being immediately eligible.

Comment: +1. @Enigmativity - no, creation of temporary variable in no way changes the eligibility for GC - end of whole method in non-optimized build/JIT, immediately after last usage in optimized one.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't think that's terribly far from the truth. The compiler doesn't technically create a variable, per se, in that no `stloc` instructions would be used. But a reference to the new instance of `Employee` does get pushed onto the stack prior to calling `GetDepartment()`, and in a sense you can think of that as an anonymous variable.

Comment: The difference is that this wouldn't prevent garbage collection of the temporary `Employee` instance whereas creating a temporary variable to hold the instance would. Have I got this wrong?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I specifically said in my answer "This isn't really what's happening but it's useful to help explain what is happening.", so I don't think it implies the compiler creates a temporary variable. Even if it did, it doesn't change when that variable would be eligible for GC. No matter what, a new instance of `Employee` has to get created. One way means that you do it yourself; the other way means the JIT does it for you. In both cases, the instance is eligible for GC as soon as there are no more references to it.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Any variable is eligible for collection as soon as the runtime can determines that there are no more active references to it within that scope. A collection cycle can happen at any time and when it does any eligible objects would be collected. It doesn't have to wait until the variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

It will be garbage collected as any other object. If there are no references to that object than it will be *eligible* for GC immediately.

Note that `GetDepartamet()` may (also would be strange in this particular case) keep reference to "employee":

```
Department GetDepartment()
{ 
     return new Department { OnlyEmployee = this}
}
```

Are there any negative effects: no, except everyone will be asking this exact question every time reading the code.

Comment: @fnostro that is correct but doesn't make any sense to do so.

Comment: i deleted my comment, but you're right, but the OP wanted to know when will Employee be GC'd, and the answer really is, 'it depends'